# Using an Excel file in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: gis, arcmap

I need to take an Excel file that includes many columns, two of which are longitude and latitude.

How do I get ArcMap to accept this file as spatial data, and map it based on the lat/long data?

My data is from [this page](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2/data) which allows for developers to  access the raw data.  I downloaded the data and loaded it into an excel file, and that's as far as I could get.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is **Add XY Data**. You can find it in the File menu (File / Add Data / Add XY Data...)

The dialog box that comes up asks you to indicate the table that was added, what columns contain XY data, and (ideally) the coordinate system of the XY data.

*Note:* Sometimes it helps to convert an Excel spreadsheet to plain CSV data first; ArcMap can be finicky about fields formatted as text instead of numbers, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add XY data will do the job. Just make sure that the values of latitude and longitude do not have trailing whitespace, otherwise, ArcMap doesn't show those columns when it prompts to choose the columns for x and y.